# Enviar autentificacion de usuario por correo

Tags: python, flask, jwt

pido disculpa de antemano si no pueden entender mi pregunta, tratare de ser lo mas claro posible.
ok
estoy diseñando un programa el cual la persona(sea usuario, admin, cliente, etc), se registre y este le envié un correo electrónico con la ruta de autentificación y así termina el proceso de registro.

explico:
1-la persona ingresa a la pagina y coloca su correo y contraseña.

2-la app genera un token de acceso y guarda el correo como identity, toma el correo y envia el token con un enlace.

3-al darle click al enlace redirige a la pagina, la app busca el token de acceso y asi permitir que el usuario termine su proceso de registro(nombre,apellido,direccion,telefono,etc).

estoy usando python junto con el framework flask.
y hasta el momento ya tengo como hacer el token de acceso y la autentificación requerida para acceder a las diferentes rutas.. 
mi problema es enviar el enlace junto con el token al correo de la persona...
la verdad soy bastante nuevo en python y flask asi que tal vez es algo sencillo de hacer....

para el envio de correo estoy usando el SMTPLIB y este es el codigo

import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def notificacion(destinatario):

```
user = 'xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
password = 'xxxxxxxxx'

#pasar las cabeceras del email
remitente = 'xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
destinatario = destinatario
asunto = 'Registro Exitoso'
mensaje = 'Se ha Registrado Plataforma: <a href="nuevoenlace">nuevoenlace</a>' 

#host y puerto SMTP de Gmail
gmail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

#protocolo de cifrado de datos utilizando por gmail
gmail.starttls()

#credenciales
gmail.login(user, password)
#muestra depuracion en la consola

#gmail.set_debuglevel(1)

#cabecera
header = MIMEMultipart()    
header['From'] = remitente
header['To'] = destinatario
header['Subject'] = asunto
mensaje = MIMEText(mensaje, 'html')
header.attach(mensaje)

#enviar email
gmail.sendmail(remitente, destinatario, header.as_string())

#cerrando la conexion SMTP
gmail.quit()
print ("Se ha enviado correo al %s:" % (destinatario))
```

de antemano doy gracias por toda la ayuda que puedan brindarme
feliz dia.

Comment: Hola Alberto, leyendo esta guia: https://stackabuse.com/how-to-send-emails-with-gmail-using-python/ me parecería que te hace falta poner el comando gmail.ehlo() antes del starttls(), te ayudó?

Comment: hola DannyTalent gracias por tu comentario, pero no hay problema con el este codigo, si lo envia al correo todo bien, el problema es que para yo accder a una vista protegido por JWT necesito agregar el header el token de acceso

Comment: No puedes setear headers con un link en un correo. En cambio debes hacer que tu endpoint sea accesible sin JWT.

Comment: hola Nache gracias por tu comentario, entonces si es como dices, que me recomendarías hacer sabiendo que en un endpoint solo usuarios que tuvieron un pre-registro pueden acceder a dicha ruta (token requerido).